# Maximum number of concurrent threads inside Windows Azure Worker Role

Tags: multithreading, azure, tcp

We are developing a server application that needs to open a lot of TCP/IP connections concurrently awaiting for some small notifications.
We are planning to use Windows Azure Cloud Services for easy scale of the server but we have only one doubt.

**What is the maximum number of concurrent threads (or tcp/ip connections awaiting for messages) that a single Windows Azure Worker Role instance can have?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure instances inside Worker Roles are regular Windows Server VM's that are managed by the Azure AppFabric controller.
As such, there is no Azure-specific limitation on the number of threads or connections that each serer can support logically.

However, be advised that servers within Azure can be of different size (power) and would physically be able to handle different number of running threads or open connections.
The theoretical max number also depends on the threads/connection themselves (how many resources they take is key).

Running a load-test on a deployed solution may help with the maximum number of threads/connections that you can open and perform adequately.

Furthermore, since Windows Azure supports scaling out, you can use something like [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) to monitor performance counters for  number of running threads or TCP/IP connections and automatically add/remove servers to your VM.

Comment: We have already planned to do some testings, resources used by those threads/connections are very small.. them are used to listening for notifications that returns only an id